# How do I reduce a function consisting of many conditional statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a function that has multiple conditional statements in it similar to the function illustrated below:

```py
def apply_function(column, function):
  if function == 'function_1':
    return function_1(column)
  
  elif function == 'function_2':
    return function_2(column)
  
  elif function == 'function_3':
    return function_3(column)
  
  elif function == 'function_4':
    return function_4(column)
  
  elif function == 'function_5':
    return function_5(column)
...
```

Is there a way I can reduce the number of conditional statements and implement the function in more pythonic way with enhanced performance?

*Please Advise.*

Comment: Do you have to pass a string? What if you just passed the function itself as the argument?

Comment: @Mark Well I'm trying to make a UDF out of this python function so I'm good as long as it works with or without a string

Comment: UDF as in user-defined functions? In that case, wouldn't users just call such functions directly? For example `(lambda x: x**2 + 3*x + 2) (5)` gives 42. It's not clear how your `apply_function` would help because `function_1, function_2, ...` are functions *you* define that also have to exist when `apply_function` is defined. @U12-Forward 's solution is useful for users who know *your* functions' names but have no access to the variables.

Comment: Using `apply_function` to wrap all the other functions would require me to register a single UDF as opposed to registering all the functions encapsulated in it as multiple UDFs.

Comment: So by UDF you don't mean functions defined by other users of your program, just yourself? What do you mean by registering and why do you want to restrict it to 1? As it stands now, you still need to `def`ine `function_1, function_2, ..., function_n` in your program in addition to `apply_function`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a dictionary and get the function from the key of the string function name:

```
def apply_function(column, function):
    dct = {'function_1': function_1, 'function_2': function_2, 'function_3': function_3
           'function_4': function_4, 'function_5': function_5}
    return dct[function](column)
```

Or use `globals`:

```
def apply_function(column, function):
    return globals()[function](column)
```